# Pulling a single char from a string and converting it to int

Tags: c++, string, char, atoi

I am trying to pull a specific char from a string and convert it to an int. I have tried the following code, but I am unclear why it doesn't work nor can I find a way to do the conversion.

```
int value = 0;
std::string s = "#/5";

value = std::atoi(s[2]);  // want value == 5
```

Comment: You'll have to skip (scan) past the non-numeric characters first.  See `std::isdigit`.

Comment: For the characters `’0’..’9’` you can subtract `’0’` to get the number that the character represents.

Comment: `atoi()` takes a C-style string (char pointer). If you just need to convert a single digit, subtract `'0'`.

Comment: `std::stoi` takes a string argument -- you can probably take the appropriate substring, and then use that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
std::string s = "#/5";
std::string substring = s.substr(2, 1);
int value = std::stoi(substring);
```

Using the `substr` method of `std::string` to pull out the substring that you want to parse as an integer, and then using `stoi` (which takes a `std::string`) instead of `atoi` (which takes a `const char *`).

Answer (score 4):

You can create `std::string` from one char and use `std::stoi` to convert to integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int value = 0;
  string s = "#/5";
  value = stoi(string(1, s[2])); //conversion
  cout << value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the manual page for `atoi()` more carefully.  The actual prototype is:

```
 int atoi(const char *string)
```

You are attempting to pass a single character rather than a pointer to a character array.  In other words, by using `s[2]` you are dereferencing the pointer.  You could, instead, use:

```
 value = std::atoi(s+2);
```

or alternatively:

```
 value = std::atoi(&s[2]);
```

This code doesn't dereference the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `std::atoi` must be `char*`, but `s[2]` is `char`. You need to use its address. And to get a valid C string from a `std::string`, you need to use the [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method.

```
value = std::atoi(&(s.c_str()[2]));
```

You should have gotten an error saying that the argument wasn't of the correct type.

Comment: `std::string` does not include a null terminator, so this answer is wrong even though it type checks.  You could end up with a segfault.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that it was `std::string`, assumed `char *`.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 I've revised it to use `.c_str()`.